# Make elements in a list clickable (PHP)

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently developing a simple web page that enables the user to:  upload an image and a corresponding caption to a DB, let the user view the images and delete them.
I have already accomplished the first two with the following code:

```
<?php
#include_once("connection.php");
$db = new mysqli("192.168.2.2", "root", "", "proyectoti");
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo "Información de servidor: ";
echo $db->host_info . "\n";

// Initialize message variable
  $msg = "";

  // If upload button is clicked ...
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    // Get image name
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));  #$_FILES['image']['name'];
    // Get text
    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text) VALUES ('{$image}', '{$image_text}')";
    // execute query
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Proyecto TI | Sube imágenes</title>
<style type="text/css">
   #content{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
   }
   form{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
   }
   form div{
    margin-top: 5px;
   }
   #img_div{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
   }
   #img_div:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
   }
   img{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 140px;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Proyecto TI | <a> Interfaz </a></h1>
<div id="content">
  <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<div id='img_div'>";
        #echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
        echo "<p>".$row['image_text']."</p>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  ?>
  <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea 
        id="text" 
        cols="40" 
        rows="4" 
        name="image_text" 
        placeholder="Di algo de esta imagen ^^"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="upload">Publicar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like this: [image: How it looks]

Now, the only part I'm missing is being able to delete an image (basically I only echo each image), how would you suggest for me to accomplish this, to make each item clickable and let's say, pop up a dialog or button to perform an action (delete from DB).

I really don't know much about PHP or CSS/HTML, any help would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Usually, when you create table, you have a unique identifier i.e. id that is unique for every row. When you build your list of images, for each image, you would store the ID somewhere. In your case maybe inside an anchor tag with `href` e.g. `delete_image.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>` so that upon clicking on the anchor tag, it will call the PHP script that will delete the image with the related ID. You may want to look at adding a field with [auto_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) so that you don't have to worry about creating your own ID.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering, I already have and id column with autoincrement, I will try to do what you suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a dialogue and ask the user before he deletes an item will require that you either go another page for deletion or use javascript for this.
In both cases, you should somehow set an identifier for your image in your html-code. 
I would suggest you give every image an id 
`'<img ... id="'.$yourImageId.'">'` 
or a data-attribute 
`'<img ... data-identifier="'.$yourImageId.'" >'`
with that identifier.

First variant:

```
...
echo '<a href="/path/to/delete/view/page.php?image=yourImageId">'
echo '<img ... id="'.$yourImageId.'"/>'
echo '</a>'
...
```

and on this delete-view-page, you just have a form that triggers your delete-code

```
<form action="/path/to/delete/view/page.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $yourImageId ?>">
</form>
<!-- after this, react with $_POST['id'] --> to the id sent to the server side and delete the image in your database -->
```

The other way is not server side rendered.
You should give your Elements some class like "my-clickable-image".After that, you have a script on your page, that looks something like the following

```
<script>
/* get your images with querySelectorAll, the . stands for class and after that your name */
var clickables = document.querySelectorAll(".my-clickable-image");
clickables.foreach(function(image){
// say that for each image, when clicked the generated function is called   image.addEventListener('click',generateShowDialogueFunc(image.getAttr("id")));
});

// generate a function(!) that reacts to an image being clicked
function generateShowDialogueFunc(imageIdentifier){
 // return a function that adds a Pop Up to the page
 // the Pop Up has approximately the code of the first options second page
 // except that now, it must create and remove elements in javascript
 return function createPopUp(){
  removePopUp();
  var popup = document.createElement("div");
  popup.setAttribute("id","deletePopUp");
  var deleteForm = document.createElement("form");
  deleteForm.setAttr("action","/path/to/file/that/deletes/given/query.php?id="+imageIdentifier);
  var deleteContents = '<p> Do you want to delete this image? </p>'
  + '<button type="submit"> yes </button>'
  + '<button onclick="removePopUp()"> no </button>'
  deleteForm.innerHTML = deleteContents;
  document.body.appendChild()
 }
}

// remove the Pop Up that can be used to delete an image from the page
function removePopUp(){
 var existingPopUp = document.getElementById("deletePopUp");
 if(existingPopUp) document.body.removeChild(existingPopUp);
}
</script>

<!-- just add some styling to make the popup show on top of the page -->
<style>
  #deletePopUp{
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 1em;
  }
</style>
```

In this case, you just call the server to delete the image, not to show the delete form.

---

I would suggest the second one but stack overflow is not made for opinion based answers.

Regarding simple security:
It looks like your users could give titles or texts to images.
try what happens if a user gives a title like `<bold>some title</title>`
and guess what would happen if the title is `<script>window.location.href="google.com"</script>` 
(XSS * hint hint *)

Regarding code structure:
If you want to do something like web development more often, think about separating your database accessing code, and your logic code from your php page template code, this is called 3 tier architecture and standard for bigger projects but i guess this is really just a first, short prototype or test.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer, it works!, regarding your suggestions I will take them into account, I know the code is messy, but my main objective right now is too make it work for testing :)

Answer (score 2):

**Within this loop:**

```
  <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<div id='img_div'>";
        #echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['image'] ).'"/>';
        echo "<p>".$row['image_text']."</p>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  ?>
```

**Personally** I would add an element to click on - like **an 'x' or whatever** - with a unique data attribute:
https://www.abeautifulsite.net/working-with-html5-data-attributes

**You have to add the unique id of the image obviously, so you can let SQL know which row to delete... Like this:**

```
 echo "<div class='delete-image' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'>x</div>';
```

Then I would link this class to an **AJAX** call to make an asynchronous request to the server and delete the image without reloading the page. It's not very hard.

**An easier solution** would be to create a new form in the loop, so you create multiple forms per image, **add a hidden field with the image id in the form** and make a submit button with the valeu 'delete' or simply 'x'.

The same way you created the check:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) { ... }
```

You can create something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete-image'])) { ... }
```

You will be carrying the image id value like a normal form input. And you can do whatever you want with it.

I would HIGHLY suggest you to look into how to work with jquery and ajax calls though.